# Ionic Android Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run my IONIC application in the android emulator but it gives me this error all the time !!!
I set the

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin,
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
```

```
[native-run] No hardware devices found, attempting emulator...
[native-run] ERR_NO_TARGET: No targets devices/emulators available. Cannot create AVD because there is no suitable API installation. Use --sdk-info to reveal missing packages and other issues.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.

        native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-d... exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: it says that you don't have any emulator system images installed. You need to install them through Android SDK manager

Comment: i allready install it

Comment: Check if you have developer option enable in your emulator.

Comment: Same problem here. Cordova runs fine on it’s own, but not together with ionic.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem and then I started Android Studio and run the emulator.

With the emulator running, I executed:

`ionic cordova emulate android`

And it works for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
--no-native-run
```

if it not resolved install native run globally

```
npm i -g native-run
```

Comment: i still have the same prb

Comment: ionic cordova run android --no-native-run

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. Then I tried opening the emulator and it worked perfectly.
I know it's late but maybe someone is still looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually create a `Virtual Device` via `AVD manager` from Android Studio. Maybe it is helpful to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

ANDROID_HOMME should be ANDROID_HOME

Comment: And did it fix your problem?

Comment: @JAB if android home wasnt set correctly, the error message will be different. It will not be from the emulator program.

Comment: i still have the same prb

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when there are no devices created in the AVD manager. You can easily fix this issue by opening the android studio and creating a target(device) in the AVD manager. Select any of the available target devices, download install them in the same AVD manager window. Once this is done, you can either test your SDK directly in the android studio by selecting the debug option and then importing your apk which can be found at -

```
platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\
```

or come back and run the following command again -

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```

But as per ionic, using Genymotion for emulation is a better option than native-run as it is too slow.